# Can IMCE or elFinder be used to insert Media tags instead of <img>?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, media, files

Is it in any possible way to get a file browser like [elFinder](https://www.drupal.org/project/elfinder) or [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/IMCE) to insert the *Media tags* supported by the [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/Media) module.

e.g.

```
[
  [
    {"type":"media","view_mode":"media_original","fid":"4","attributes":   
      {"alt":"","class":"media-image","height":"35","style":"float: right;","typeof":"foaf:Image","width":"33"}
    }
  ]
]
```

Instead of having insert image tags?